With Openpyxl, how to get get image information that can't be got with sheet._images?
I have a .xlsx file that contains images in one of its worksheet 'sheet'. These images are visible in Excel. However, if I open that sheet with Openpyxl, the list sheet._images contains no element.
I'm sorry that it's not convenient to share that .xlsx file on Internet. And I've no idea about how to create a .xlsx file with such weird characteristic.
Can anyone tell me how to get image information of such a .xlsx file?
I've tried to get image information with sheet._images but failed, as sheet._images is an empty list. I expect to get information of those images in a worksheet of a .xlsx file.

You can unzip the Excel file and look in 'xl/media/' to see what Image files the workbook contains, and extract them from there.

Maybe the images where put into the cells using IMAGE function. If so, one could try to read those formulas and get the image URL from first argument. Nevertheless the images should be in /xl/media too as @moken told.

@moken You are right! I can find those images under xl/media/. Thanks!
And, is there any way I can manipulate those images as if we normally use sheet._images?

@Axel Actually I've no idea about how those images were added. By "to read those formulas and get the image URL from first argument", I'm wondering how/where I can read those formulas??

@Axel OK, I see. Unfortunately, I failed to find the =IMAGE(...) function in that .xlsx file. But anyway, thanks for your reply!

IF the images are not links in and Excel formula/function and don't show in ._images then extracting from the archive is the only alternative I have if Openpyxl is the only choice (even thought extracting from the archive does not involve Openpyxl). It seems extracting from the archive is also the choice for the author of Openyxl. Another module like Xlwings should also be a workable option though off hand I dont have or know of any example code.

In Excel sheets images are usually displayed as shapes of a sheet drawing. The sheet drawing is a layer hovering over the sheet cells. Shapes in this layer are anchored to the cells but are not cell content. Such images, and only such images, are read by current openpyxl and provided in list Worksheet._images.
Since version Microsoft Office 365 images also can be the result of a cell formula using the IMAGE function. Furthermore images can be placed in cells as the cell content. See Insert Picture in-cell in Excel. Both types of images are outside the sheet drawing and thus are not read by current openpyxl.
Office Open XML, the file format of *.xlsx files, is mainly a ZIP archive. For *.xlsx files there is a directory  /xl/mediain that ZIP archive. This directory contains image files for each embedded image in that *.xlsx-workbook. This will be images in sheet drawings, images as cell content (from =IMAGE(...) as well as from in-cell-inserted pictures), images in headers/footers and so on. Thus if one unzips the *.xlsx file, one will find all embedded images in  /xl/media.
