How to get the Position of Embedded Images in an Excel File Using Python?
I'm working with an Excel file (.xlsx) that contains embedded images. I need to extract the position (cell reference) of these images programmatically using Python. Here's what I've tried so far:
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Using openpyxl and openpyxl-image-loader:
I wasn't working for embedded images.
Unzipping the Excel file and inspecting the contents:
I extracted the images from the xl/media directory. However, I'm struggling to find the related XML files (xl/drawings/drawing*.xml or xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet*.xml.rels) that map these images to specific cell positions.
Checking for other relevant XML files:
I've also checked the workbook.xml and other standard locations but couldn't find the necessary mappings.
I could extract green pics positions with using openpyxl but it's not working for small pics in cells.

Unfortunately, this the edit doesn't provide enough detail to help. I don't see why the Openpyxl Image loader code wouldn't work here. How were the images inserted, What type of image file were the originals, what was the original size, were they adjusted to the size of the cell?  See @Axel Richter's comment below, does that scenario apply?

I assume you don't mean using the formula
=IMAGE("https://<URL path>/image.png", "image")

since the formula is in the actual cell.
So look at Openpyxl Image loader, it shows you how

for image in ws._images:
    # Get row and column info where the image is located
    row = image.anchor._from.row + 1
    col = string.ascii_uppercase[image.anchor._from.col]


thanks for your suggestion! I've tried this. It works for images on the sheet but still it doesn't work for images which is embedded in the cell.

Be more specific, How? ' images which is embedded in the cell ' Edit your Post, show what you are working with.

@moken: "images which is embedded in the cell". Brave new world of Microsoft 365 ;-). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78502815/with-openpyxl-how-to-get-get-image-information-that-cant-be-got-with-sheet-im/78510473#78510473.

While it is technically possible to map image positions and find the relationship ID from the XML files, I wouldn't recommend it. The reason is that the placement of relationship IDs might change, as it has in the past. However, extracting images themselves can be done by unzipping the *.xlsx file, where all embedded images can be found in the /xl/media directory. Hopefully, the library developers will implement a more straightforward feature for this soon.
